# Protractor URL is not opening but test is passing on running from Command Prompt

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have started Protractor. I have created a project.
My myFirstTest.js clss is like this:

describe("MyFirstTest", function() {

```
it("Adding Two Numbers", function() {

    browser.get("https://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/");


    element(by.model("first")).sendKeys("5");

    element(by.model("second")).sendKeys("5");

    element(by.id("gobutton")).click();

    expect(element(by.className("ng-binding")).getText().trim().toEqual("10"));

});
```

});

My config.js class is like this:
exports.config = {

```
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
specs: ['./Day/myFirstTest.js'],
```

};

The myFirstTest.js class is inside a "Day" folder. My WebDriver is also up and running. But, when I run the code from command prompt, by specifying "protractor config.js" , the chrome browser opens, but the url does not open, and closes. The message shows as 
"No specs found
Finished in 0.003 seconds

[02:06:00] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of Web
[02:06:00] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed".

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Show your project folder structure which can illustrate the relationship of `config.js`, 'Day' folder.

Comment: No its fine...I have got it where it was going wrong.

Comment: In this line, there was error in brackets.
expect(element(by.className("ng-binding")).getText().trim().toEqual("10"));
Also, i had to remove the trim function, and had to give specs: ['../day/firsttest.js']in config.js file.